# Localizing Epoch Time with pytz in Python

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, epoch, pytz

Im working on converting epoch timestamps to dates in different timezones with pytz.  What I am trying to do is create a DateTime object that accepts an Olson database timezone and an epoch time and returns a localized datetime object.  Eventually I need to answer questions like "What hour was it in New York at epoch time 1350663248?"

Something is not working correctly here:

```
import datetime, pytz, time

class DateTime:
    def __init__(self, timezone, epoch):
        self.timezone = timezone
        self.epoch = epoch
        timezoneobject = pytz.timezone(timezone)
        datetimeobject = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp( self.epoch )
        self.datetime = timezoneobject.localize(datetimeobject)

    def hour(self):
        return self.datetime.hour

if __name__=='__main__':
    epoch = time.time()
    dt = DateTime('America/Los_Angeles',epoch)
    print dt.datetime.hour
    dt = DateTime('America/New_York',epoch)
    print dt.datetime.hour
```

This prints the same hour, whereas one should be 3 or so hours ahead.  Whats going wrong here?  I'm a total Python beginner, any help is appreciated!

Comment: You are using the wrong terminology here. The epoch is *always* 1-1-1970, midnight UTC. What you have is a UNIX timestamp, which is an offset from the epoch. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_epoch

Comment: just a variable name, you could call it `epoch_time` it makes no difference to the problem

Answer (score 40):

`datetime.fromtimestamp(self.epoch)` returns localtime that shouldn't be used with an arbitrary timezone.localize(); you need `utcfromtimestamp()` to get datetime in UTC and then convert it to a desired timezone:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

# get time in UTC
utc_dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(posix_timestamp).replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)

# convert it to tz
tz = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
dt = utc_dt.astimezone(tz)

# print it
print(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'))
```

Or a simpler alternative is to construct from the timestamp directly:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

# get time in tz
tz = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(posix_timestamp, tz)
# print it
print(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'))
```

It converts from UTC implicitly in this case.

Answer (score 6):

For creating the [**`datetime`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) object belonging to particular timezone from a unix timestamp,  you may pass the [**`pytz`**](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) object as a `tz` parameter while creating your `datetime`. For example:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import pytz

>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(1350663248, tz= pytz.timezone('America/New_York'))
datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 19, 12, 14, 8, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/New_York' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>)
```

You can get the list of all timezones using **[`pytz.all_timezones`](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#helpers)** which *returns exhaustive list of the timezone names that can be used*.

Also take a look at [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) wiki.

Answer (score -3):

```
epochdt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(epoch)
timezone1 = timezone("Timezone/String")
adjusted_datetime = timezone1.localize(epochdt)
```

Working from memory, so excuse any syntax errors, but that should get you on the right track.

EDIT: Missed the part about knowing the hour,etc. Python has great [Time/Date Formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html). At pretty much the bottom of that link is the table showing how to pull different attributes from the datetime object.

Comment: Thats pretty similar to the initial approach, but implementing this still prints out the same hour (in the __main__ code above).  Basically its 8am where I am right now.  What im trying to figure out is how to get the above code to print 8 and 11m ie for America/Los_Angeles and America/New_York respectively.